# Sonar Qube DeprecatedRuleDefinitions Error

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to build a new plugin for SonarQube and getting following error on plugin installation.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.server.rule.DeprecatedRuleDefinitions.define(DeprecatedRuleDefinitions.java:63) ~[DeprecatedRuleDefinitions.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RuleDefinitionsLoader.load(RuleDefinitionsLoader.java:44) ~[RuleDefinitionsLoader.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.RuleRegistration.start(RuleRegistration.java:95) ~[RuleRegistration.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:433) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:176) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:54) ~[PlatformLifecycleListener.class:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
```

I checked my code and found that this error comes from CheckList.java class under the java-checks-{version}.

Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any question relating to the development of plugins should be asked on development mailing list : http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/. You'll also have to provide the version of the SonarQube server you're using.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will put my question there.